# Trade paperback comic about a "vinyl hunter" hired to find demonic vinyl records

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror

I am looking for the title of a trade paperback comic. The plot consists of a "vinyl hunter" hired to find and retrieve several vinyl records. When listened to, the records kill the listener, most involving supernatural means.
One individual wants all of the records.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I swear I actually bought this about 3 years ago.

Comment: I know it was independently published, I do not recall the cover.